# Python prime number program not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, primes

I'm creating a Python program to determine if a number is prime or not. This is what I have:

```
 print("Please enter your number:") 
number = int(input())


if number > 2: 
    for i in range (2,number):
        if (number % i) == 0:
            print(number, "is not prime")
            break
        else:
            print(number, "is prime")
            break
else:
    print(number, "is not prime")
```

It works for every use case except 2. Why? And how can I fix it?

Comment: This does _not_ work for "every use case except 2". Try with the number 9. You have `print "is prime"` inside your loop, but you can't know that it is prime until the whole loop has finished. Also, you're skipping straight to "is not prime" if the number is 2.

Comment: I fixed it. I had to put the "else: number is prime" outside the for loop.

Answer (score 3):

Because 2 is not greater than 2, so it falls in the else condition.

To fix it you have to create a special case for 2:

```
print("Please enter your number:") 
number = int(input())

if number > 2: 
    for i in range (2,number):
        if (number % i) == 0:
            print(number, "is not prime")
            break
    else:
            print(number, "is prime")
elif number == 2:
    print(number, "is prime")
else:
    print(number, "is not prime")
```

Edit: Using for-else as @Azat Ibrakov suggested

Comment: This still doesn't work properly to find primes. According to this, 9 is prime.

Comment: @khelwood Should be fixed

Comment: `number = int(input()) as type int` isn't valid Python syntax, and isn't part of the OP's code [ah, it was part of the OP's _original_ code.]  How is this even running?

Comment: @DSM it was originally part of OP's code but he edited it later

Comment: @fedterzi: yeah, so it seems.  Usually it's a good idea not to post code you haven't tried yourself, though; askers often make typos but answers shouldn't. :-)

Comment: you can use `for-else`

Answer (score 0):

Please find below my code, I bypassed 2.

Value '2' never go through for loop so it prints 'Prime' by default.

For all others it works as expected.

```
for i in range (1,100):
    self.bar(i)

def bar(self,number):

    if number > 1 :
        for i in range(2,number):
           r = number % i
           if r == 0 :
               return
        print(str(number) + ' : Prime')
```

> 2 : Prime  3 : Prime  5 : Prime 7 : Prime 11 : Prime 13 : Prime 17 :
>   Prime 19 : Prime 23 : Prime 29 : Prime 31 : Prime 37 : Prime 41 :
>   Prime 43 : Prime 47 : Prime 53 : Prime 59 : Prime 61 : Prime 67 :
>   Prime 71 : Prime 73 : Prime 79 : Prime 83 : Prime 89 : Prime 97 : 
>   Prime